# Going from trig identities to hyperbolic identities

Tags: complex-analysis

Show how $$\cosh^2z-\sinh^2z=1$$  $$\cosh(z_1+z_2)=\cosh z_1 \cosh z_2 + \sinh z_1 \sinh z_2$$

follows from $$\sin^2z+\cos^2z=1$$  $$\cos(z_1+z_2)=\cos z_1 \cos z_2 - \sin z_1 \sin z_2$$

Approach: For the first identity I was thinking if we set $\sin z=-i\sinh(iz)$ and $\cos z=\cosh(iz)$ in the third identity, so we get $$\cosh^2(iz)-\sinh^2(iz)=1$$

but I don't know how to get rid of the $i$s. I would use a similar approach for the second identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $z$ as a dummy variable, or let $w=iz$, you already have the identity. Since the $z$ from one identity doesn't necessarily correspond to the $z$ in another.

Comment: we can map any complex number by using z  right?, so the identity would satisfy.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Yes, exactly. So there's no need to eliminate $i$.

Comment: what about the second one?. How would you do it?

Comment: @TheMathNoob It is exactly the same idea, e.g. the left hand side would be $\cosh (iz_1 + iz_2)$

Comment: But can I start at cosh and end up at cos? Don't I have to do it the way around?

Comment: @TheMathNoob The two are interchangeable, for example, $\sin z= i\sinh (iz)$ implies that $\frac{\sin (-iz)}i = \sinh (-i^2 z) =\sinh z$, so $i\sin (iz) =\sinh z$. Then the identities can be transformed into each other.